# In Google Photos, how share (or copy) entire Favorites album?

Tags: google-photos, favorites

Unlike other albums, the share icon isn't present in the upper right when the album is open. Is there a way to share it?

Alternately, if I could copy the album as it exists now, then I could share that album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the photos by selecting the first one, then holding down shift, then selecting the last one.

Create a new album with this selection.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do this. A work around is

1. Open Favorites album.
2. Select all photos, either by checking or checking on the day that contains one or more. This is the step that could use more work, e.g. a select all way.
3. Add to a new album.